# Following Flutter Dev steps for preparing android app causes gradle to fail to install

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, release

I am currently working with the flutter ble master pluggin to do some bluetooth testing. I have the example working on my virtual environment just fine. I wanted to publish the app so I followed the instructions on flutter.dev for doing so (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android). I have completed all the steps without issue, however when I go to build an APK file I get the following error:

"* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\flutter_ble-master\flutter_ble-master\example\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Command: C:\flutter_ble-master\flutter_ble-master\example\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder."

I have rolled back the changes I made when following the document and isolated the issue to the second part of the "Configure signing in gradle" step. In this step you perform the following changes:

Replace the following:

```
content_copy
   buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
```

With the signing configuration info:

```
content_copy
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

By removing this change I can build an APK and run the app on my phone no problem.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a key.properties file with a keyAlias, keyPassword, storeFile, and storePassword set? The key.properties file should exist under the android folder at the same level as gradle.properties and settings.gradle.

Comment: Yep, i have that all set up.

Comment: Maybe add your whole gradle file?